# Dojo combobox check values

Tags: javascript, regex, combobox, dojo

I'm currently working with Dojo and i'm fairly new to it.
I'm running into a problem where I want to check the contents of a combobox if the userinput is valid or not.
If the input is invalid I want to prevent a POST action from happening after submit is being pressed.
Invalid input would be characters like {}<>;' etc. I only want to allow text and numbers with a regexp, the input must be more than 0 and less than 20, so the field may also not be blank.

The user MUST be able to enter his/her own custom text and not only choose from the already available items, if that was the case I should've used a FilteringSelect.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a small code sample of a possible solution.

You should set the "required" property of the ComboBox to true and include a "regExp" property as shown below:

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
        require(["dojo/store/Memory", 
                 "dijit/form/ComboBox",
                 "dijit/form/Button",
                 "dojo/_base/window",
                 "dojo/domReady!"],
        function(Memory, ComboBox, Button, win, ready){
            var stateStore = new Memory({
                data: [
                    {name:"Alabama", id:"AL"},
                    {name:"Alaska", id:"AK"},
                    {name:"Arizona", id:"AZ"},
                    {name:"Arkansas", id:"AR"},
                    {name:"California", id:"CA"},
                    {name:"Colorado", id:"CO"},
                    {name:"Connecticut", id:"CT"},
                    {name:"Delaware", id:"DE"}
                ]
            });

            var box = new ComboBox({
                name: "state",
                value: "",
                store: stateStore,
                searchAttr: "name",
                required: true,
                regExp: "[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,19}"
            });
            win.body().appendChild(box.domNode);

            var submit = new Button({
                label: "Submit",
                style: "margin: 0 0 0 10px;",
                onClick: function() {
                    if ( box.isValid() ) {
                        // Do the post
                        var boxValue = box.get("value").trim();
                    } else {
                        // Invalid entry
                    }
                }
            });
            win.body().appendChild(submit.domNode);
        });
    </script>
```

If you need to allow for spaces in the RegExp, then:

```
regExp: "[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{1,19}"
```

Also, a relevant [link](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/#1_9dijit_form_ComboBox_regExp);